# WP - share taxonomies with users and a custom type

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to make custom taxonomies for users in Wordpress admin panel. So, for example a user could have taxonomies like `region`, `department`, `role`, `company`. I have made post type of user categories, where an admin could create such taxonomies for users.

```
<?php
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('intranet-categories', [
        'labels' => [
            'name'                  => 'Bruker kategori',
            'singular_name'         => 'Bruker kategori',
            'menu_name'             => 'Bruker kategori',
            'name_admin_bar'        => 'Bruker kategori',
            'add_new'               => 'Legg til ny',
            'add_new_item'          => 'Ny Bruker kategori',
            'new_item'              => 'Ny Bruker kategori',
            'edit_item'             => 'Rediger Bruker kategori',
            'view_item'             => 'Vis Bruker kategori',
            'all_items'             => 'Alle Bruker kategorier',
            'search_items'          => 'Søk',
            'parent_item_colon'     => 'Forelder',
            'not_found'             => 'Fant ingen Bruker kategori.',
            'not_found_in_trash'    => 'Fant ingen Bruker kategori i søppelkassen.',
        ],
        'description'           => 'Bruker kategori',
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => true,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_in_menu'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => ['slug' => 'intranet-post'],
        'capability_type'       => 'post',
        'has_archive'           => true,
        'hierarchical'          => false,
        'menu_position'         => null,
        'menu_icon'             => 'dashicons-editor-ol',
        'supports'              => ['title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail'],
    ]);
});
```

And then I have registered taxonomies and shared them with `intranet-post`, and `users`.

```
register_taxonomy('department', ['intranet-categories', 'intranet-post'], [
        'labels' => [
            'name'              => 'Avdeling',
            'singular_name'     => 'Avdeling',
            'search_items'      => 'Søk',
            'all_items'         => 'Alle avdelinger',
            'parent_item'       => 'Forelder',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Forelder',
            'edit_item'         => 'Rediger avdeling',
            'update_item'       => 'Oppdater avdeling',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Opprett avdeling',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Ny avdeling',
            'menu_name'         => 'Avdelinger',
        ],
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => ['slug' => 'avdeling'],
    ]);

    register_taxonomy('region', ['intranet-categories', 'intranet-post'], [
        'labels' => [
            'name'              => 'Region',
            'singular_name'     => 'Region',
            'search_items'      => 'Søk',
            'all_items'         => 'Alle region',
            'parent_item'       => 'Forelder',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Forelder',
            'edit_item'         => 'Rediger Region',
            'update_item'       => 'Oppdater Region',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Opprett Region',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Ny Region',
            'menu_name'         => 'Regioner',
        ],
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
        'rewrite'           => ['slug' => 'avdeling'],
    ]);

    register_taxonomy('industry', ['intranet-categories', 'intranet-post'], [
        'labels' => [
            'name'              => 'Bransje',
            'singular_name'     => 'Bransje',
            'search_items'      => 'Søk',
            'all_items'         => 'Alle bransjer',
            'parent_item'       => 'Forelder',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Forelder',
            'edit_item'         => 'Rediger bransje',
            'update_item'       => 'Oppdater bransje',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Opprett bransje',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Ny bransje',
            'menu_name'         => 'Bransjer',
        ],
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'bransje'],
        ]
    );

    register_taxonomy('role', ['intranet-categories', 'intranet-post'], [
        'labels' => [
            'name'              => 'Rolle',
            'singular_name'     => 'Rolle',
            'search_items'      => 'Søk',
            'all_items'         => 'Alle roller',
            'parent_item'       => 'Forelder',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Forelder',
            'edit_item'         => 'Rediger rolle',
            'update_item'       => 'Oppdater rolle',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Opprett rolle',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Ny rolle',
            'menu_name'         => 'Roller',
        ],
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'rolle'],
        ]
    );

    register_taxonomy('company', ['intranet-categories', 'intranet-post'], [
        'labels' => [
            'name'              => 'Selskap',
            'singular_name'     => 'Selskap',
            'search_items'      => 'Søk',
            'all_items'         => 'Alle selskaper',
            'parent_item'       => 'Forelder',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Forelder',
            'edit_item'         => 'Rediger selskap',
            'update_item'       => 'Oppdater selskap',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Opprett selskap',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Ny selskap',
            'menu_name'         => 'Selskaper',
        ],
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'show_ui'           => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite' => ['slug' => 'selskap'],
        ]
    );
```

I have managed to add taxonomies to users in the admin menu as well, like this:

```
function add_user_taxonomy_admin_page() {
    $categories = get_object_taxonomies('intranet-categories');
    foreach($categories as $category) {

        $tax = get_taxonomy($category);

        if (!is_object($tax) OR is_wp_error($tax))
            return;

        add_users_page(
            esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
            esc_attr( $tax->labels->menu_name ),
            $tax->cap->manage_terms,
            'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=' . $tax->name
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_user_taxonomy_admin_page');
```

But, I am wondering how can I get those taxonomies on edit user page in the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Options 1: Since 2.3 there is the ability to create taxonomies for any object type, not just posts. In WordPress, there are several object types like Posts, Users, Comments and Links. Justin Tadlock (big WP reference) handles your same issue. http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/10/20/custom-user-taxonomies-in-wordpress

Options 2: If you mean to have the same question like https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10566/is-it-possible-to-add-taxonomies-to-user-profiles the answer is here 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6163/commenting-in-user-profile-page/6165#6165